# javascript window.location remove SSL protocol

Tags: javascript, redirect, ssl

**EDITED**: THIS WAS A SERVER REDIRECT ISSUE, not sure if question should be deleted.

I'm in a page with valid SSL certificate lets say:

```
 https://www.example.com/something
```

I execute this:

```
 window.location = '/other/folder';
```

And the redirection goes to a non SSL version:

```
 http://www.example.com/something
```

Anyone know why and how to prevent that?

(I want to understand why this happend so dont ask me to just add https:// at the beginnin), Thanks!

Comment: more than likely is due to server redirect. Might be set to revert away from `https` except for certain paths

Comment: I can access to the path if I enter it on the URL... I'm running the command on firebug console.. all assets are loaded using https on the same host...

Comment: log location to console and see if that gives you clues

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but maybe you are running that code from a JS file that is hosted/sourced via plain http:// and the browser is using that as the relative protocol?

I went to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_cricket ran `window.location = '/'` in the console and it took me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page. Works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your edit, so this post is only for people like me who should encounter a similar problem.

When on Firefox, just ensure your redirection take place **after** the dom of your redirection page is **completely loaded**. To validate this hypothesis, just replace your automatic window.location by a manual redirection (HTML input type="button"). The redirection should be ok. Then, just add a javascript setTimeout on your redirection, or use a dom selector to ensure your page is loaded (e.g. jquery : 
$('document').ready(function() {            $('#my_redirect_form').submit();            });)

Comment: Welcome to SO, but how does this answer the question? What "hypothesis" are you talking about?